# Is there a closed form of the logarithmic infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\log(1+x^n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form

In a [recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642431/1122499), I defined the function $\Psi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\log(1+x^n)$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and proved the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\Psi(x)=2\log(2)-1$ by [bounding it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wh2izkfpnr) using the integral test as
$$\color{blue}{-\dfrac{2\log(2)-1}{\log\left(x\right)}}\leq\color{purple}{\Psi(x)}\leq\color{red}{-\dfrac{\log\left(1+x^{-1}\right)\left(1+x\right)-1}{{x\log\left(x\right)}}}$$
However, I was asking myself (and now you): **is there a way to express $\bf\Psi(x)$ using already known functions?** I don't mind if the closed form uses standard special functions like Bessel functions, the incomplete Gamma function, elliptic integrals, $q$-analogs, etc. But I won't count as valid expressions that involve *ad hoc* functions (that is, special functions that aren't standard defined specifically to express this function in a closed manner). I know that its Taylor series is given by

$$\Psi(x)-\log(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\log(1+x^n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_kx^{kn}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_k x^{(k+1)n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_{k-1}x^{kn}$$
$$=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{d\vert m}\alpha_{d-1}\right)x^m=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{1<d\vert m}\frac{(-1)^{d}}{d-1}\right)x^m\ \text{ where } \alpha_k:=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } k=0\\ \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} & \text{ if } k\geq1\end{cases}$$
$$\boxed{(1)\ \Psi(x) = \log(2)+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{1<d\vert m}\frac{(-1)^{d}}{d-1}\right)x^m\ }$$
but this leads to nothing since I don't know how to express the Dirichlet convolution involved in its terms. Also, as pointed out by @TymaGaidash, we can also express it as the following Lambert series $$\boxed{(2)\ \Psi(x) = \log(2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(1-x^{-n-1})}}$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash I know. In fact, I defined $\Psi(x)$ precisely to tackle [an infinite product similar to that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4641071/1122499).

Comment: The sum is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(1-x^{-n-1})}$ and is related to [Lambert series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series)

Comment: Thanks @TymaGaidash :) but I also know that. Everytime a Dirichlet convolution of that kind appears on the terms of a Taylor series, there’s a Lambert series associated to it. However, I can’t simplify the Lambert series either. Do you?

Comment: Just an observation: the unit circle is a natural boundary for $\Psi(x)$.

Comment: This is a very interesting function, for sure